# Unable to merge branch back into trunk after repository re-arrange

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I'm facing an issue with merging a branch back into a tree on SVN, this is my situation

My branch was created some time ago

Since then, we have re-arranged our SVN repository, and this project has moved under a different heirarchy.

Now, I would like to merge that branch back into its trunk

I seem to be getting a lot of `tree conflicts`, and it seems that when merging, it is trying to reference the old location of the source, which now doesn't exist since we have moved the project in the repository

So in short, make branch, move project, try to merge back to trunk, why do I keep getting the tree conflicts? Is there a way to "de-reference" the old location of the source code?

SVN : 1.6.11
TortoiseSVN 1.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do in this situation is update the brach with the main trunk changes, resolve any conflicts and then merge the branch back to the main trunk, it's the only way you won't break the trunk.

It will be a lot a of work in this case since you've done a lot of changes to the structure of the project and you didn't update your branch with the changes. But it's safer than hammering the code to the trunk.

A tool like [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) can help with the merge. It's paid but they have a 30 day trial if you don't want to purchase it.